# How to clear the image in textField on the tap of textField,Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nstextfield

I have set the image to textFiled using rightmodeview on clicking button,
now what I want is, I want to hide the image on tapping the textField without touching button?
Help me out

Comment: set `textfield.rightView = nil` in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method.

Comment: thanks, it works on button click event but i want to hide image without clicking button!! any idea please!!

Comment: please check my updated comment above. when you tap the textfield, it's `textFieldDidBeginEditing` delegate method will be called. you can set the rightview of textfield as nil there.

Comment: I tried this one,but no changes image is not disappearing.

Comment: Show or post your tried code here

Comment: Why dont you use the rightmode "UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing" ?
self.txtField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeUnlessEditing;

Comment: NSTextfield is for mac. Is this iOS or macOS?

Answer (score 0):

this code is working for me

```
 -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {     
      //set right view nil
 }
```

and make sure you set delegate of UITextField for your textfield

Add below code in viewDidLoad

```
yourTextField.delegate = self;
```

Comment: thanks, i got it :) but that  [yourTextfiled delegate] = self       should be like  [yourTextField  setDelegate: self];    i changed it and i got the result

Comment: actually i am swift developer but i have little bit idea about objective c..if my answer is realy helpful for you then accept my answer so other also can solution from it,

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {  
textfield.rightView=nil;
//Do other stuff,if you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created sample one and I tried it works fine.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtFldImage;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  txtFldImage.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
  txtFldImage.rightView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"boss-icon.png"]];
}
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
  txtFldImage.rightView = nil;
}
```

When run the app

[image]

When I enter or touch the textField

[image]